# Redirecting Subdomain to Subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I try to add the following logic to a .htaccess file:

subdomain.domain.xx make a redirect to subdomain.domain.xx/subdomain/
xy.domain.xy redirect to xy.domain.xy/xy/ (it should work with every subdomain without adding new rewrites)

i found a lot of solutions to redirect subdomain.domain.xx -> domain.xx/subdomain, but nothing like i need... below you find the code i try out.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www)?.domain.ch/$
RewriteRule .* http\://%1$1.domain.ch/%1$1 [I,R=301]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in the `.htaccess` file of your subdomain's root directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine on
Redirect permanent /index.html http://subdomain.domain.xx/subdomain/
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your fast help, and sorry, i forgot to say that it have to be dynamic - say: subdomain1.domain.xy/ -> redirects subdomain1.domain.xy/subdomain1/ and subdomain2.domain.xy/ -> redirects to subdomain2.domain.xy/subdomain2/

Comment: So every subdomain redirects to domain.com/subdomain/? If so, you'd probably be better off using DNS wildcards.

Comment: in DNS i add *.domain.xy -> IP and then in Webserver i give this ip, so every subdomain points to this ip. In Webserver-Root directory every User can create his subdirectory and it should work directly with the subdomain.